# GNU make auto dependencies depends on directory

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

(Sorry for bad English, I'm German)

Hello Programmers,

I'm using GNU make for my C++ Project, but I have some trouble with the auto-dependencies:
If I execute "make objects/file.o" it tells me that objects/file.o is already up to date even if a file included by source/file.cpp has changed.
The weird thing is, that if I change DEP_DIR and OBJ_DIR to "." everything works.
Here is my makefile (incomplete):

```
SRC_DIR := source
DEP_DIR := dependencies
OBJ_DIR := objects

$(shell mkdir -p $(dir EXE_PATH))

-include $(addprefix $(DEP_DIR)/, $(NAMES:=.d))

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
        $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC_DIR)/$*.cpp -o $@
        $(CXX) -MM $(CFLAGS) $^ > $(DEP_DIR)/$*.d

$(EXE_PATH) : $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(NAMES:=.o))
        $(CXX) $(LINK_FLAGS) $^ -o $(EXE_PATH)

all : $(EXE_PATH)

run : 
        $(EXE_PATH)

carun : $(EXE_PATH)
        $(EXE_PATH)

clean:
        rm -f EXE_PATH
```

I would be thankful if anyone could explain this weird problem to me.

Comment: It should be `CXX`, not `CPP`. `CPP` is C preprocessor, and `CXX` is a C++ compiler

Comment: Otherwise, I recommend you to use https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md it does all these auto dependencies for you and you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about the error you're seeing: macros and functions that appear in the target or prerequisite lists are expanded immediately as the makefile is parsed, long before make starts to run rules which would match patterns and replace `%`.  So, in this line:

```
$(depDir)/%.d : $(srcPath)/%.cpp $(shell cat $(depDir)/%.d)
```

the `shell` function is invoked while make is reading in the makefile, and at that time it will just use the verbatim string `%.d` because no pattern matching has happened yet.

As mentioned in other answers, this is not the right way to do auto-dependency generation anyway (you don't actually show how these `.d` files are generated so it's hard to give specific advice).

If you want to learn about how to do this a more modern and efficient way, you might check out [this blog post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how dependency generation is done nowadays, you can generate dependencies as a [side effect](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) of compilation. Also use the built in variable names `CXX`, `CPPFLAGS`,`CXXFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`, and recycle make's built in recipes.

```
.PHONY: all
all: Release/$(EXE_NAME)
    echo "finished building... in theory"

Release/$(EXE_NAME): CC := $(CXX)
Release/$(EXE_NAME): $(OBJS) | Release
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(objDir)/%.o: CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP 
$(objDir)/%.o: $(srcPath)/%.cpp | $(objDir)
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(objDir) Release: ; mkdir -p $@

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```